# Can we prove that $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n a_k \rightarrow \frac{1}{2}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Let $a_n$ be equal to 0 or 1, where it is randomly equal to these numbers. If we do the limit $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n a_k$, it SEEMS to approach 1/2, but with this information we cannot prove the problem. I thinked it while flipping coins and playing heads or tails, and thinking about the probability of one or the other falling. Consider that the tail have value 0 and the head have value 1, so if we sum the amount of times the coin flips to heads with the amount of times the coin flips to tails, and divide by the number of times we did the experiment, we will have a value that is approximately the probability of flipping head, with I think that approaches the real value.

Comment: In what sense do you want convergence?
Read up on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers

Comment: There is a link with The conjecture of Kean, in concern with KOLAKOSKI sequence (1,2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say $S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n a_n$, and suppose that $a_n$ are 0 or 1 with equal probability. One sense of convergence is to say that $\lim_{n\to \infty}S_n/n =1/2$ means that, for every $\epsilon > 0$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{P}(|\tfrac{S_n}{n} - \tfrac{1}{2}|> \epsilon) = 0$.

Using Chebyshevs inequality you can prove this pretty easily.

$$\mathbb{P}(|\tfrac{S_n}{n} - \tfrac{1}{2}|> \epsilon) < \frac{1}{4n\epsilon^2} \to 0$$

Answer (score 3):

By central limit theorem (in the limit $n\to\infty$), what you're asking is equivalent to the expected value of $a_k$. Assuming the probability for $a_k$ being $0$ and $1$ is uniform and equal $(p(0)=p(1)=1/2)$, we have that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^na_k=\mathrm E[a_k]=p(0)\cdot 0+p(1)\cdot 1=\frac{1}{2}\cdot 0+\frac{1}{2}\cdot 1=\frac{1}{2},$$
like you wanted to prove.